# Multiple File Upload not working

Tags: 2010, list, document-library, file-upload

When  i try to upload multiple files it gives me error . [image]

Can someone provide a server side fix . Also the multiple upload doesnt work for Mozilla ,Chrome . Are there any third party tools to make multiple upload work for Mozilla ,safari ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the below change in the web.config file and multiple file upload functionality started working . The IIS setting blocks the multiple file upload functionality.

```
<verbs>
      <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
</verbs>
```

Comment: where to insert this tag in web.config?

Answer (score 6):

The "Upload Multiple Documents" command is an ActiveX control. It does not work with Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc.

Please see [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691367) for details.

Comment: But why do i get error when i try to upload in IE ?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question. What happens in the ULS or Fiddler when the Upload Multiple Documents command fails in IE? Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I use IE 11 and let me check in fiddler

Comment: Just to verify, are you using IE11 32bit? Have you tried older versions of IE?

Comment: browser shld not be problem because testing environment is working fine on same browser

Comment: ULS says : MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List .

Comment: If you are certain that the browser and its settings are identical on your test & prod environments, then I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Was going to suggest more browser tests including navigating to the upload.aspx without modal dialog (e.g. `http://yoursite/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={guid}&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1`).

Comment: Can you try to upload documents using IE11 in compability view?

Comment: Why does MS say it supports all the browsers ?

Comment: Is this applicable for SP2010 only or for sp2013 as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the .net patch to support IE versions 10+?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx